# Combine two txt files into one dictionary with corrections

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have two "txt" files that contain several names and addresses or phone numbers. What I need to do is to read the files, delete possible spaces before or after the first and the last letters, and combine them in one single dictionary that uses a "phone", "address" and "name" keys if those values are present in the text file.
For example:

file `phonefile`:

```
Marco: 347 8987989
  giorgio  : 06 89786765
 Mauro B.: 3489878675
Ciro : 07897878
L. De La: 09877887
```

file `addrfile`:

```
Giorgio : via Verdi, 23
 M. Bianchi:Piazza Milano, 1
   L. De La : via A. Einstein, 12
 Ciro: via Pio
```

Must become:

```py
{'giorgio': {'phone': '06 89786765'},
'Marco': {'phone': '347 8987989'},
'Giorgio': {'address': 'via Verdi, 23'},
'L. De La': {'address': 'via A. Einstein, 12', 'phone': '09877887'},
'Ciro': {'address': 'via Pio', 'phone': '07897878'},
'Mauro B.': {'phone': '3489878675'},
'M. Bianchi': {'address': 'Piazza Milano, 1'}}
```

This is what I tried so far:

```py
def f_phone_addr(phonefile, addrfile):
from collections import defaultdict
e = open(phonefile)
e.readlines()
f = open(addrfile)
f.readlines()
out = defaultdict(dict)
for name, phonenumber in phonefile:
    out[name]['phone'] = phonenumber
for name, address in addrfile:
    out[name]['address'] = address           
return out
```

I need some help please!

Comment: @user714965 the question is "how to effectively combine two text files into one dictionary that correctly categorizes names, phone numbers and addresses based on its contents?"

Comment: You have posted some code. What's wrong with that code? Is there an error which you like to ask about, or do you just want anybody to provide you some code which you can copy/paste?

Comment: @user714965 Well, for instance I get this error when trying to run the code: for name, phonenumber in phonefile:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: Ok, now we have a question! You should edit your question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically just need to add line clean up and processing:

I would do something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def clean_line(line):
    name, _, value = line.partition(':')
    return name.strip(), value.strip()

def process_file(dic_, file, key):
    for line in file:
        name, value = clean_line(line)
        dic_[name][key] = value

def f_phone_addr(phonefile, addrfile):

    out = defaultdict(dict)
    with open(phonefile) as pf, open(addrfile) as af:
        process_file(out, pf, 'phone')
        process_file(out, af, 'address')
    return out
```

Comment: I get the "NameError: global name 'out' is not defined" error. When I try to define "out" as "{}" I get this instead:line 69, in process_file
    out[name][key] = value
KeyError: 'Marco'"

Comment: @test123: fixed. you seriously need to start with basic Python tutorial.

Comment: That's why I'm still just a student... :( Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
phones = dict((k.strip(), v.strip()) for k, v in
              [l.split(":") for l in
               [l.strip() for l in
                open('phonefile').read().split('\n') if l]])
addrs = dict((k.strip(), v.strip()) for k, v in
             [l.split(":") for l in
              [l.strip() for l in
               open('addrfile').read().split('\n') if l]])

dict((k, {'phone': phones.get(k), 'address': addrs.get(k)}) for k in
      set(phones.keys() + addrs.keys()))
```

**Result**

```
{'Ciro': {'address': 'via Pio', 'phone': '07897878'},
 'Giorgio': {'address': 'via Verdi, 23', 'phone': None},
 'L. De La': {'address': 'via A. Einstein, 12', 'phone': '09877887'},
 'M. Bianchi': {'address': 'Piazza Milano, 1', 'phone': None},
 'Marco': {'address': None, 'phone': '347 8987989'},
 'Mauro B.': {'address': None, 'phone': '3489878675'},
 'giorgio': {'address': None, 'phone': '06 89786765'}}
```